# How to use try with data.withUnsafeBytes() in Swift 5, Swift5?

Tags: xcode, try-catch, swift5, xcode12

If I option click on withUnsafeBytes in my code, the declaration states that the function throws:

```
func withUnsafeBytes<R>(_ body: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R
```

When I put in do try catch in my code (see below) I get a warning for the try:

> No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression

and a matching warning for the catch:

> 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

Is my code incorrect or is this a problem with Xcode?

```
func getIntValue(data:Data)->Int
{
    var d = -1
    
    do {
        d = try data.withUnsafeBytes {
            $0.load(as: Int.self)
        }
        
    } catch {
        return d
    }
    return d
}
```

Your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `throws -> rethrows` syntax does the following:

- If the code in the closure body contains a throwing function the error is rethrown and you have to add `try`
- If there is no throwing function nothing happens and you must not use `try`.

In your example the second case occurs so remove `try` and the `do - catch` block

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is something like load that throws errors, or is it up to the programmer to count the bits and make sure the data is correctly formatted for the type it is being turned into? Sorry I don't have the points to up vote your answer, but thank you!

Comment: There are no errors because the `load` API just reads bytes from memory so the developer is responsible for *counting the bits*.